# Improve heavy work in a loop in multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a little problem with my data processing.

```
public void ParseDetails()
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < mListAppInfo.Count; ++i)
    {
        ParseOneDetail(i);
    }
}
```

For 300 records, it usually takes around 13-15 minutes.

I've tried to improve by  using `Parallel.For()` but it always stop at some point.

```
public void ParseDetails()
{
    Parallel.For(0, mListAppInfo.Count, i => ParseOneDetail(i));
}
```

In method `ParseOneDetail(int index)`, I set an output log for tracking the record id which is under processing. 
Always hang at some point, I don't know why..

```
ParseOneDetail(): 89 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 90 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 243 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 92 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 244 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 93 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 245 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 247 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 94 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 248 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 95 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 99 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 249 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 100 ...
_ <hang at this point>
```

Appreciate your help and suggestions to improve this.
Thank you!

`Edit 1`: update for method:

```
private void ParseOneDetail(int index)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ParseOneDetail(): " + index + " ... ");
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = mListAppInfo[index];

    var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = htmlWeb.Load(appInfo.AppAnnieURL);

    // get first one only
    HtmlNode nodeStoreURL = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(Constants.XPATH_FIRST);
    appInfo.StoreURL = nodeStoreURL.Attributes[Constants.HREF].Value;
}
```

`Edit 2`: This is the error output after a while running as `Enigmativity` suggest,

```
ParseOneDetail(): 234 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 87 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 235 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 236 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 88 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 238 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 89 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 90 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 239 ...
ParseOneDetail(): 92 ...

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---
> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get(Uri uri, String method, String path, HtmlDocum
ent doc, IWebProxy proxy, ICredentials creds) in D:\Source\htmlagilitypack.new\T
runk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1355
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.LoadUrl(Uri uri, String method, WebProxy proxy, Ne
tworkCredential creds) in D:\Source\htmlagilitypack.new\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\Ht
mlWeb.cs:line 1479
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url, String method) in D:\Source\htmla
gilitypack.new\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1103
   at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url) in D:\Source\htmlagilitypack.new\
Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1061
   at SimpleChartParser.AppAnnieParser.ParseOneDetail(ApplicationInfo appInfo) i
n c:\users\nhn60\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FunToolPack\SimpleChartPa
rser\AppAnnieParser.cs:line 90
   at SimpleChartParser.AppAnnieParser.<ParseDetails>b__0(ApplicationInfo ai) in
 c:\users\nhn60\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FunToolPack\SimpleChartPar
ser\AppAnnieParser.cs:line 80
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass21`2.<ForEachWorker>b__17
(Int32 i)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__
6(Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceled
Exceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationTo
ken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int
32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWit
hState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](TSource[] ar
ray, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Act
ion`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEveryt
hing, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`
1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState
, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithE
verything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Act
ion`1 body)
   at SimpleChartParser.AppAnnieParser.ParseDetails() in c:\users\nhn60\document
s\visual studio 2010\Projects\FunToolPack\SimpleChartParser\AppAnnieParser.cs:li
ne 80
   at SimpleChartParser.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\nhn60\documents\
visual studio 2010\Projects\FunToolPack\SimpleChartParser\Program.cs:line 15
```

Comment: Maybe your `ParseOneDetail` method isn't thread-safe?

Comment: @KooKiz - You think? (sarcasm) LMAO

Comment: Post the code for `ParseOneDetail` if possible.

Comment: @xjaphx - You've posted some very basic code that certainly doesn't contain the error. The error, therefore, must be in the code that you **haven't** posted.

Comment: I've updated the code for method `ParseOneDetail()`

Comment: Could it be that the HtmlWeb class has a maximum number of open connections?

Comment: I use `HtmlAgilityPack` for parsing data, `HtmlWeb` is one of class supported. Checking it now!

Comment: Are any of the classes involved disposable, and not being disposed? (Including in the call that stores uris).

Comment: The site you are trying to connect may block some connections when flooded.

Comment: @L.B: do you have any suggestion to improve performance in my heavy work method? I'm still stuck ...

Comment: @xjaphx you may try to limit the max thread num to 2(ParallelOptions class), if it works you can increment it.

Comment: @L.B: when I set thread number, like 5 or above, it results several records really fast, but getting slower and slower and `Connection Time Out`...But if I set from 1->4, time consuming is the same as running without using `Parallel`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Put a `try`/`catch` around the `HtmlWeb.Load` call and see if you still have the same error. If this "fixes" it don't fall for it being the answer - it would just be a temporary kludge.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per se, but could you try modifying your code to work like this and let us know if you still have the error?

```
public void ParseDetails()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(mListAppInfo.ToArray(), ai => ParseOneDetail(ai));
}

private void ParseOneDetail(ApplicationInfo appInfo)
{
    var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = htmlWeb.Load(appInfo.AppAnnieURL);

    // get first one only
    HtmlNode nodeStoreURL = 
            document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(Constants.XPATH_FIRST);
    appInfo.StoreURL = nodeStoreURL.Attributes[Constants.HREF].Value;
}
```

Comment: I've updated in `Edit 2` above, still error but different one, may relating to connections

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment out every line from `ParseOneDetail` and check if it finishes running.

If it does (it should), uncomment the first half, and check if it'll finish again. Keep doing this binary search until you work out exactly which line is stopping it from running. There's likely to be something in that line that isn't thread-safe.